# indent and text nodes on xslt transformations with .net

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm transforming XML to XML and would like to indent the result automatically.
So I'm using `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>`
When running this through .net4 compiled transform, it works well as long as there is no text node on the output.
Once I'm adding some text `<xsl:text>some text</xsl:text>` the indentation of the whole xml file is gone and the result XML consists of some very long lines instead (well formed but unreadable...)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
      <!--xsl:text>some test</xsl:text-->
      <Test1/>
      <Test2/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Test1 />
  <Test2 />
</Root>
```

Result when removing the comment from `<xsl:text>some test</xsl:text>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>some test<Test1 /><Test2 /></Root>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine - could you show an example where you add some text?

Comment: @Filburt did you try this with .net (4) compiled transform? I know that other xslt processors behave differently.

Comment: Yes, I used .Net 4.0 and `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: @Filburt I've added some example to demonstrate the problem

Comment: I could reproduce it with your example - my first try used an identity transform for `Test1`and `Test2`. As soon as you add other elements after `<xsl:text>` indentation is lost. It will however start working with the next <xsl:apply-templates>`.

Comment: Add the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute on the `xsl:template` instruction and try.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Ok, with `xml:space="preserve"` it now preserves both indentation and newline! But the problem now is that it preserves **all** whitespace (even though I've specified `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`). Since I want to keep my xslt file readable and maintainable I can't abstain from adding whitespace to my xslt source. But this is a step in the right direction. Is there a way to solve this problem and consider only whitespace within `<xsl:text>` nodes?

Comment: @AmirGonnen: I don't understand your question at all. I personally never bother to introduce indentation manually. `xsl:output indent="yes"` does this for me -- together with `xsl:strip-space elements="*"`. You should be using an XSLT IDE such as Visual Studio or oXygen (I am using the XSelerator) and such an IDE typically formats the XSLT code in an indented , readable form.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I am using Visual Studio and it idents the xslt source very well. I think you misunderstood my last comment. Your suggestion to add `xml:space="preserve"` solved one problem (output xml identation) and created another (all whitespace in xslt is copied to the output xml). I don't want to avoid whitespace when editing the xslt although this could have solved this problem.

Comment: @AmirGonnen: In this case you may decide to put the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute not on `xsl:template` but on the innermost element (literal result element or XSLT instruction) where this is necessary -- you have full flexibility here.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I didn't succeed doing that. When I add the `xml:space="preserve"` on literal elements I get an internal error. Even if it worked it would probably work recursively, so whitespace would be preserved not only between the elements but also inside them. (But I need the newlines only between elements)

Comment: @AmirGonnen: What is the source XML, and what is the wanted result that you want to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Indenting specified with**:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

**[affects only the treatment of white-space-only nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-XML-Output-Method)**.

Whenever you specify non-whitespace-only text nodes, you must provide for them your own indenting -- yourself.

Comment: I understand that the `<text>` node will not be affected by the indent, but why adding a text node affects all other non-text nodes? I couldn't see on the XSLT 1.0 W3C Recommendation anything that explains that except from "_It is usually not safe to use indent="yes" with document types that include element types with mixed content._" (which doesn't really say what should happen in this case)

Comment: @AmirGonnen: The quoted text from the XSLT 1.0 W3C Recommendation clearly says that this is "not safe" -- which is the same as saying "not specified what will happen", or "unpredictable" -- exactly what you have witnessed.

Comment: You said _Whenever you specify non-whitespace-only text nodes, you must provide for them your own indenting_. The problem is that I must provide my own indenting not only for the non-whitespace-only text nodes, but also for the **xml nodes** which are siblings of the text nodes. Suppose all I want to do is to add a newline between two xml nodes. This means I need to provide my own indenting for all xml nodes which are siblings to the newline... Do you know of a way to mitigate this? (currently my only workaround is to add a comment node and a newline within it, which is not very clean)